# What is causing gray space on a Google Map using v3 API?

Tags: magento, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to load a map as per the example in the Google documentation, but it's not loading. I tried using `resize`, but it's not loading correctly. This map is behind a tab rendered with the Prototype JavaScript Framework which magento uses. It loads correctly when not behind a tab.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #map_container { height:500px; width:700px;margin:0;}
</style>
<div id="map_container">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&sensor=true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Event.observe( window, "load", function() {
        var myOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            zoom: 6,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
        ;
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    });
</script>
```

The map is shown with grey parts that cover most of the map and the UI elements are not fully initialized. I tried using `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");`, but it does not seem to do anything. This div is inside a lot of divs.

Comment: It is likely a CSS overlap or style problem. Can you share a link to your page? Or maybe set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? It's almost impossible to diagnose this kind of problem without being able to take a look.

Comment: You need to use the `resize` event when the map is made visible, but there's no information here about how you do that, so it's impossible to advise on how to implement the trigger.

Comment: you can see an example of the tabs here: http://demo-admin.magentocommerce.com/index.php/admin/customer/edit/id/1/  user:admin pass:123123, if the map is behind a tab it does not render correcly. if it is on the first tab or you open firebug it renders correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example how to add new tab "GMaps" in Magento "Product Edit" (new tab "id" is 'product_info_tabs_GMaps')

PHP part

> class My_Gmaps_Block_Adminhtml_Tabs_Gmaps extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
>
> ```
> public function __construct() {
>
>   parent::__construct();
>
>   $this->setTemplate('my/gmaps/tabs/gmaps.phtml');
>
> }
> ```
>
> /*.............................*/
>
> }

Template part 'pwron/gmaps/tabs/gmaps.phtml':

> ```
> <style>#map_canvas {width:100%; height:600px;}</style>
> <div class="map" id="map_canvas"></div>
>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     var GMaps = Class.create();
>     GMaps.prototype = {       ....................        }
>     var gmaps = null;
>     function switchGMapsTab(tab){
>         if ( tab.tab.container.activeTab.id == 'product_info_tabs_GMaps'){
>             if (!gmaps){
>                 gmaps = new GMaps({});
>                 gmaps.update();
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     varienGlobalEvents.attachEventHandler('showTab', switchGMapsTab);     <script>
> ```

trouble way
1. Created Map
2. Tab showed (not loads all tiles)

best way
1. Tab showed 
2. Created Map

Comment: you are right, the best way is to have magento load the map on tab load, good catch, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you. But I managed to find the solution with this simple code.

First, go to the file where you put the tab template, search for the `<li>` tag that load your map tab and put this inside:

```
<li onclick="reloadmap()">
```

And in the map script right after the

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

put this:

```
function reloadmap(){
  //when you resize the map, you lose your zoom and your center
  //so you need to get them again here
    z = map.getZoom();
    c = map.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  //and set them again here
    map.setZoom(z);
    map.setCenter(c);
}
```